# Rails For Loop View

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following code:

```
<tbody>
   <%= Item.each do |item|=%>
   <tr>
      <th><%= item.rev =%></th>      <=========
      <th><%= item.name =%></th>
   </tr>
   <%= end =%>
</tbody>
```

However I am getting a syntax error on the inidcated line. There is data in the database(Test case). No idea what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The equals to signs you have are wrong. Try as below:

```
<tbody>
   <% Item.each do |item|%>
   <tr>
      <th><%= item.rev %></th>     
      <th><%= item.name %></th>
   </tr>
   <% end %>
</tbody>
```

The <%= should only be used for expressions that need to be evaluated.

To help understand embedded ruby see this link 
http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/web.html

Answer (score 1):

The expression for erb tags is <% #code %>
now if we want to print that tag too then we apply <%= #code %>
i.e. only one '=' sign is used and that too on left side.
Also in line each iterator there nothing can be printed, hence no '=' sign in 
that line, similar is the case with tags containing 'end'.

Hence your code should look like

> `<tbody>`
>        <% Item.each do |item| %>
>             `<tr>`
>                  `<th>`<%= item.rev %>`</th>`
>                  `<th>`<%= item.name %>`</th>`
>             `</tr>`
>        <% end %>
>   `</tbody>`