# dynamic price range creating rails looping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having following html for describing price range is it possible to created in rails loop

```
<ul>
                    <li class="auto-view selector">
                        <a class="active callback-price">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="0-1000" />Rs. 1000 and Below
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="auto-view selector">
                        <a class="active callback-price">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="1001-5000" />Rs. 1001 and Rs. 5000
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="auto-view selector">
                        <a class="active callback-price">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="5001-15000" />Rs. 5001 and Rs. 15000
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="auto-view selector">
                        <a class="active callback-price">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="15001-25000" />Rs. 15001 and Rs. 25000
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="auto-view selector">
                        <a class="active callback-price">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="25001-35000" />Rs. 25001 and Rs. 35000
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="auto-view selector">
                        <a class="active callback-price">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="35001-45000" />Rs. 35001 and Rs. 45000
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="auto-view selector">
                        <a class="active callback-price">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="45001-55000" />Rs. 45001 and Above
                        </a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
```

I need to create this in single 



 by running in loop

Is it possible if so how can I create it can anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the loop in your view example shown below

```
<% Model.each do |v| %>
  <%= v.column %>
<% end %>
```

[Rails For Loop View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13166847/rails-for-loop-view)

Similar question here.

Hope it helps

Comment: I dont have model for this to do this like you mentioned