# enable a user to select 5 items from a drop down

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm very new to rails and trying to build a feature in my app where a user should be able to pick a skill from a drop down menu which will be listed on their show page.

In the edit page I have 5 drop down menus but in the show page it only takes the first selected item and repeats it 5 times. If anyone can help me trouble shoot that would be great help ! (tried finding a similar issue on here but couldn't find one )

edit.html.erb

```
  </tr>
            <tr>
              <td> <%= select("user", "skills", User::SKILLS) %></td><BR>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td> <%= select("user", "skills", User::SKILLS) %></td><BR>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td> <%= select("user", "skills", User::SKILLS) %></td><BR>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td> <%= select("user", "skills", User::SKILLS) %></td><BR>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td> <%= select("user", "skills", User::SKILLS) %></td><BR>
            </tr>
```

show.html.erb

```
    <tr>
        <td>skills:</td>
        <td><%= current_user.skills %></td>
    </tr>
```

user.rb

```
     SKILLS = ["","Administrative", "Analytical", "Artistic/Creative", "Budgeting", "Communicaton", "Computer", "Conflict Reslution", "Creating Ideas", "Creating Procedures", "Creating New Solutions", "Customer Service", "Decision Making", "Fundraising", "Handling Complaints", "Innovative", "Leadership", "Learning", "Logical Thinking", "Maining High Levels of Activity", "Negotiating", "Networking", "Organizational", "Planning", "Problem Solving", "Reporting", "Team Work", "Technical", "Time Management", "Training"]
```

Comment: I'd really suggest using a for loop to create all those tables. You're creating a lot of boilerplate for yourself at the moment, which could come back to bite as the app expands.

Comment: how about changing `skills` for `skills[]` ?

Comment: @RailsKiddie I've been trying to figure out how to put that in a proper loop, but have been struggling to get the loop to work!  (I'm a total newbie)

Comment: @lcguida do you mean changing skills for skills[] in my user.rb?

Comment: @Amena there's a nice example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13166847/rails-for-loop-view if you need something to work from :)

Comment: @RailsKiddie thank you so much!  super helpful link.

Comment: @RailsKiddie wonder if you could help me up with this problem I'm having with the loop. i've written my loop like this         
 <td> User Goals </td>
       <% select User::SKILLS.each do |skill|%>
        <tr>
            <th><%= current_user.skills %></th>
         </tr>

and in my models I've written this method 

  def select_skills
    skills = []
    5.times do |i|
      return select_skills
    end
  end

but get the error wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2..5)

Comment: @Amena are you able to raise it in a new question and post the link?

Comment: @RailsKiddie http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42863120/loop-a-select-drop-down-menu-5-times