# loop a select drop down menu 5 times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Basically I want a user to be able to select their top 5 skills from 5 different drop down menus that will later be viewed on a user's show page

**users controller:**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

      def new

            @user = User.new
          end

          def show
            @user = User.find(params[:id])
            @events = @user.events

          end

          def create
            @user = User.new(user_params)
            if @user.save
              session[:user_id] = @user.id
              redirect_to root_url
            else
              render "new"
            end
          end

          def edit
            @user = current_user
          end

          def update
            @user = current_user
            @user.update_attributes(user_params)

            if @user.save
              redirect_to user_path(current_user)
            else
              render "edit"
            end
          end

          def upload
            uploaded_io = params[:user][:picture]
            File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', uploaded_io.original_filename), 'wb') do |file|
              file.write(uploaded_io.read)
            end
          end


          private

          def user_params
            params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :first_name, :last_name, :region, :volunteer_position, :summary, :date_of_birth, :picture, :hours, :org_admin, :skills, :goals)
          end
        end


    users model:

          SKILLS = ["","Administrative", "Analytical", "Artistic/Creative", "Budgeting",
          "Communicaton", "Computer", "Conflict Resolution", "Creating Ideas",
          "Creating Procedures", "Creating New Solutions", "Customer Service",
          "Decision Making", "Fundraising", "Handling Complaints", "Innovative",
          "Leadership", "Learning", "Logical Thinking", "Maintaining High Levels of Activity",
          "Negotiating", "Networking", "Organizational", "Planning", "Problem Solving",
          "Reporting", "Team Work", "Technical", "Time Management", "Training"]


          def select_skills
            @skills = []
            5.times do |i|
              return i.skills
            end
          end
```

**users show.html.erb**

```
<tr>
    <td>skills:</td>
    <td><%= current_user.skills %></td>
</tr>
```

**edit.html.erb**

```
 <tr>
     <td> User Goals </td>
       <% select User::SKILLS.each do |skill|%>
       <% @skill = Skills.order.first(5) %>
 <tr>
   <th><%= current_user.skills %></th>
 </tr>
 <% end %>
```

the error message:

> ArgumentError in Users#edit
>   wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2..5)

Comment: Are you able to post the full error message, and also the model, view and controller you have and the location of each file within the app directory structure? I could be wrong but I would have expected the method you've written to be in the controller

Comment: @RailsKiddie updated it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting an argument error on this code snippet:

```
<tr>
  <td> User Goals </td>
  <% select User::SKILLS.each do |skill|%>
  <% @skill = Skills.order.first(5) %>
</tr>
```

Because select requires at least two parameters. I personally find select_tag much more straight forward:

```
<tr>
  <td> User Goals </td>
  <%= select_tag "skills", options_for_select(User::SKILLS) %>
</tr>
```

That will give you a single select with all your skills. You can easily make 5 selects with a loop:

```
<tr>
  <td> User Goals </td>
  <% 5.times do |i| %>
    <%= select_tag "skills<%=i%>", options_for_select(User::SKILLS) %>
  <% end %>
</tr>
```